# Is there a way to use dynamic collection names in AQL?

Tags: arangodb, aql

If I have a collection that contains collection names in it, is there a syntax in AQL that allows you to use dynamic collection names?

Here is an example of what I'm looking for. A collection called `master` has many documents, with a `.state` of `Active` or `Disabled`. The collection has a key called `collection_name` which is the name of another collection in this database.

```
FOR doc IN master 
FILTER doc.state == 'Active' 
    FOR c IN COLLECTION(doc.collection_name)    <--- invented command called COLLECTION
    RETURN {
      'collection_name': doc.collection_name,
      'contents': c
    }
```

I'm trying to retrieve all documents from all collections marked as `Active` in the `master` collection.

Is there a way to do this in one AQL query without having to break it up into an initial query on `master` followed by n queries for each of the collections returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've concluded from [this](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1138) ArangoDB issue there is no way to truly use dynamic collection names.

However you could use any AQL function as workaround. See the last comment on the issue for a full explanation.